# Trigger off canvas menu upon adding product to cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

When a user clicks 'Add to Cart', rather than redirecting them to the cart page, I would like to trigger an off-canvas menu that contains the contents of their shopping cart.

I'm using http://git.blivesta.com/drawer for the menu implementation

The menu can be toggled/opened with javascript, but I'm unsure as to how to trigger the opening of the menu when a user clicks 'Add to Cart'.

Ideally, I would like this to be possible, without reloading the page.

Has anyone implemented anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

The basic recipe is this, and you can definitely do it without a page reload:

- In your JS, listen for the form's submit event
- Prevent the default submit
- Ajax submit the form's data to the Commerce `addToCart` controller
- Grab the result of this call...
- If error - show error
- If cart - JS pass the cart's data off to your drawer system and print out the cart that way (that's the quickest way, or you can just ajax load in a Craft template to where you have your drawer, the `cart` variable in that will have the updated cart data)